# Stuff unique Record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some sample records below. I am interested in counting the ID records where they have only X values. For example, I need to count ID = 10720, and 11120 since both have only X values. If they have X and other like XY or AB values, for example like ID = 10586, I would not count it.

Currently, I am using this two steps in SQL and spreadsheet to get my result for now but not efficient.

```
ID  LocationCode        Dates
10720   VA  X       3/20/2012 1:00:00 PM
10586   DC  X       7/12/2003 7:00:00 AM
10586   DC  X       8/2/2003 4:44:25 AM
10586   DC  XY      2/21/2019 8:00:00 AM
10892   NY  X       5/3/2009 4:00:00 PM
10892   NY  X       5/5/2009 6:30:00 AM
10892   NY  X       5/7/2009 11:45:00 AM
10892   CA  AB      4/5/2016 8:40:00 AM
10932   CA  AB      8/3/2009 4:00:00 AM
10932   CA  AB      8/11/2009 5:30:00 PM
10932   CA  X       5/8/2010 4:00:00 AM
11120   FL  X       11/25/2010 10:27:00 AM
11120   FL  X       12/8/2010 9:02:00 PM
11120   FL  X       12/28/2010 10:30:00 AM
```

Step 1:

```
select 
  location,
  string_agg(code, '') as CODE,
  count(distinct ID) as count
from TEMP
group by location
```

Step 2: taking the result in spreadsheet and filter out the unique X values.

Is there a way in SQL server that can produce the result directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing :

```
select count(*)  
from     
(
select id table where code = 'X'    
EXCEPT
select id from where code != 'X'    
) tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.code <> 'X');
```

Or, if you prefer, two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having min(code) = max(code) and min(code) = 'X'
     ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
select ID 
from TEMP
where Code = 'X'
group by ID
having count(distinct Code) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input! Joey

Answer (score 0):

Summing the results you have will give the total for 'X'.

Something like

```sql
    select code, sum(count) as count 
    from (
        select 
        location,
        string_agg(code, '') as CODE,
        count(distinct ID) as count
        from TEMP
        group by location
    ) codes_aggregated
    group by code
    having code = 'X'
```